# Joining two graphs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

**Suppose I have $f_1(x)=x$**

And i restrict its domain as $\color{blue}{(-\infty,0]}$ using $g_1(x)=\dfrac{x}{\frac{1}{2\left(x-0\right)}\left(x-0-\left|x-0\right|\right)}$

Resulting in :

[image: 1]

**Now, suppose i have $f_2(x)=\sin{(x)}$**

And i restrict its domain to $\color{blue}{(0,\infty)}$ using $g_2(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{\frac{1}{2\left(0-x\right)}\left(0-x-\left|0-x\right|\right)}$

Resulting in :

[image: 2]

---

> **Now I want a new equation which can join $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ in one single equation. How should i achieve it?**

I mean $\large g_{\text{joined 1+2}}(x)$ would look like :

[image: 3]

Also i want a single equation which is **NOT** of the form of $\color{red}{
    f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    x& \text{if } x\leq 0\\
    \sin{(x)}& \text{if }  x> 0
\end{cases}}$

---

**My attempt :**

I tried using $(y-g_1(x))(y-g_2(x))=0$ but they don't seem to work...

They seem to be working with $y=x,x \in (-\infty,0]$ and $y=2x, x \in (-\infty,0]$ as :

[image: 4]

---

> So how to proceed?
>
> *Please help. Thanks!*

Comment: What's wrong with splitting casewise?

Comment: @Meelo Just curious! The way i restricted the domain of x and sin(x) was also not using condition but was using single equation...!!

Comment: @NeilRoy I have another answer you might like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I was your age, I discovered a way to do this, although it's a bit artificial. Suppose that you want a function, that has an unrestricted domain, which takes on the values of a function $f(x)$ when $x<a$ and $g(x)$ when $x>a$. Then $h(x)$, the function we are looking for, can be given by 
$$h(x)=f\left(\frac{|x-a|-(x-a)}{2}\right)+g\left(\frac{|x-a|+(x-a)}{2}\right)-f(0)\left(\frac{|x-a|+(x-a)}{2}\right)-g(0)\left(\frac{|x-a|-(x-a)}{2}\right)$$

Suppose we wish to define a function which takes on the values of $f(x)$ for $x\in(a,b)$ and $g(x)$ for $x \in (c,d)$. Then we define $h(x)$, the function we are looking for, to be

$$h(x)=f\left(\left[\frac{|x-a|}{x-a}-\frac{|x-b|}{x-b}\right]\frac{x}{2}\right)+g\left(\left[\frac{|x-c|}{x-c}-\frac{|x-d|}{x-d}\right]\frac{x}{2}\right)-f(0)\left(\frac{|x+b|+(x+b)+|x-a|-(x-a)}{2}\right)-g(0)\left(\frac{|x-d|+(x-d)+|x-c|-(x-c)}{2}\right)$$

I used to think of these constructions to be made by 'switches'. There is a better way to do this if my memory serves me right but this is all I can remember right now. I'll be sure to edit if I remember how I did it before. Nice question!

Comment: How about $f(x) \in (a,b)$ and $g(x) \in (c,d)$? I guess its a bit complex...! But thanks!

Comment: I'll edit now to include this case.

Comment: Please do! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry to ask another question but just give me a hint so as to what will happen if I want to use [ instead of ( as in $[a,b)$ ?

Comment: Not at all. It's a pretty safe assumption that $f$ is continuous, so  $\lim_{x\to a} f\left(\frac{|x-a|}{x-a}\right)=f\left(\lim_{x \to a}\frac{|x-a|}{x-a}\right)$. Let me know if you'd like another hint.

Comment: No thanks! But pretty amazing answer!

Comment: Somehow, I used this method on $\mathrm{sgn}(x)$ ($f(x)=-1$ and $g(x)=1$), and the result simplified to $x$.

Comment: I suspect you just set $h(x)=\frac{|x|-x}{2}$ or something of the sort. But that would mean that $g(x)=x$. We can set $a=0$, $f(x)=\frac{-x}{x}=-1$, and $g(x)=\frac{x}{x}=1$ to find that $\mathrm{sgn}(x)=\frac{|x|-x}{2x}+\frac{|x|+x}{2x}$

Comment: @Archaick See [this document](http://pastebin.com/SyHdtR7x) for my reasoning. Also, where did you get the $2x$ for the denominators from?

Comment: @legionMammal978 You can't just set $f(x)=-1$ and $g(x)=1$ and let them cancel as this gets rid of their dependence on the 'switches' ($\frac{|x|-x}{2}$ for $f(x)$ and $\frac{|x|+x}{2}$ for $g(x)$) as this automatically means the function won't have its domain sectioned as we want it to. What I did was take the function $f(x)=-x$ and plug in $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ into the formula for $h(x)$, thereby effectively letting $f(x)=-1$ while still restricting its domain (same thing for $g(x)$).

Comment: @Archaick I found an answer but in a different way. It is posted below.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 I think you will find less inconsistencies with my answer below but it already includes the $\text{sgn}$ function so........

Comment: @Archaick Please check your answer for $\sin(x)\in(-\pi,0)$ and $(x-\pi)^2$ from $(\pi,2\pi)$, I think your answer needs updating.

Answer (score 7):

How about this?
$$y=\frac{x-|x|}{2}+\sin\left(\frac{x+|x|}{2}\right)$$

Comment: This feels like cheating in this case (because the absolute value is also defined piecewise), but I really like this answer.

Comment: Can you suggest for $y=f_1(x) x \in (a,b)$ and $y=f_2(x) x \in (c,d)$ ? And Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MichaelBurr Alternatively (though still cheaty), you could define it as $\sqrt{x^2}$.

Comment: @mathlove I thought you might want to check my answer.

Comment: @mathlove Your answer is a specific example of Archaik's answer so......

Answer (score 1):

I found shorter ways of generalizing this. I am as old as you are so I am glad to know someone has a similar kind of interest as I do. I notice that when $f(0)\neq{0}$ and $g(0)\neq{0}$ my method could be quicker.

Basically you can take two functions and "fuse" them by the floor function with exponents (as long as the function does not have a restricted domain ex.$\sqrt{x}$). I found that using this I can bring $f(x)\in(-\infty,a)$ and $g(x)\in[a,\infty)$ to a single equation. 
 $${{f(x)}^{\frac{-\text{sgn}{\lceil(x-a-1)+.5}\rceil+1}{2}}} {g(x)}^{\frac{{\text{sgn}\lceil(x-a-1)+.5}\rceil+1}{2}}$$

To switch which domain of the function $x=a$ is included in, replace the "ceil" function with the "floor" on your computer. Also you may need to use "sign" instead of "sgn" for the signum function.

Unfortunately this fusion works best when were fusing functions that have no undefined intervals. With $f(x)\in(a,b)$ and $g(x)\in(c,d)$, where $a<c$ and $b<c$ if there is a gap between $b$ and $c$ one must use manipulations to get...

$$\left({{\left(\left(f(x)\right)^{-1}+1\right)}^{\frac{\text{sgn}{\lceil(x-a-1)+.5}\rceil-\text{sgn}\lceil(x-b-1)+.5\rceil}{2}}}{{\left(\left(g(x)\right)^{-1}+1\right)}^{\frac{\text{sgn}{\lceil(x-c-1)}+.5\rceil-\text{sgn}\lceil(x-d-1)+.5\rceil}{2}}}-1\right)^{-1}$$

However this equation has an undefined region making it less artificial.

Now you can easily use this approach for more than one function. Here are the "switches" of my method as the exponents of functions.

$c_n(x)$ includes $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

$\left(\left(\prod_{n=0}^{k}{\left({\left({c_n}(x)\right)}^{-1}+1\right)}^{{d_n}(x)}\right)-1\right)^{-1}\quad$ Union of all defined intervals ("undefining" unwanted intervals).

$d_0(x)=\frac{-\text{sgn}\lceil(x-a-1)+.5\rceil+1}{2}$ $(-\infty,a)$

$d_1(x)=\frac{\text{sgn}\lceil(x-a-1)+.5\rceil+1}{2}$ $(a,\infty)$

$d_2(x)=\frac{\text{sgn}\lceil(x-a-1)+.5\rceil-\text{sgn}\lceil(x-b-1)+.5\rceil}{2}$ $(a,b)$